# Serve S3 behind cloudfront with 2 origins

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I've a CF distribution with 2 origins:

- S3
- ALB

This distribution has an alternate CNAME.

Depending on the path, I want some files being served by S3, other by the ALB.

I've 3 behaviours with the following paths:

- `assets/*` with S3 as origin
- `uploads/*` with the alb as origin
- `default` with the same `uploads/*`'s origin but with a different cache policy

In the S3 bucket there are 2 folders: `svg` and `v2`

when I try
`curl -I https://myalternate.domain.name/assets/svg/mysvg.svg` or
`curl -I https://xxxxxx.cloudfront.net/assets/svg/mysvg.svg`
I've 404.

If I get them from web I can see

```
<Error>
  <Code>NoSuchBucket</Code>
  <Message>The specified bucket does not exist</Message>
  <BucketName>myalternate.domain.name or cloudfront endpoint</BucketName>
  <RequestId>Q7Z1NAP8HV0PCEM4</RequestId>
</Error>
```

For the other paths everything is alright.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

What the CloudFront does when it receives the `https://myalternate.domain.name/assets/svg/mysvg.svg` request is that it will fetch the object stored in S3 using the key `assets/svg/mysvg.svg`. That's why it returns 404 since the actual key of that object is `svg/mysvg.svg`. The solution is to either add `assets/` prefix to every object in S3 or use a Lambda@Edge function to rewrite the origin request.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but It doesn't work... I copied the 2 folders into assets so that the new key is assets/svg/mysvg.svg. Same error.